# "Live" Processor hang under Ubuntu 11.10, how to diagnose/fix?

Tags: ubuntu

We recently upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10 on a virtual server.  Since the upgrade,  the server will periodically "hang" with processor use at zero (according to monitoring).  Monit is still running and sending out notifications,  cron will restart Apache etc.,  but we cannot ssh into the box and http does not start.

Can anyone give pointers to where to start?

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a question for serverfault...

Comment: It seems perfectly on-topic here. If @1kenthomas wants it moved we can, but otherwise I'll leave it

Comment: (See op's comment http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22808/live-processor-hang-under-ubuntu-11-10-how-to-diagnose-fix#comment32117_22810 saying it went away)

Answer (score 0):

1. try to remove/disable ACPI and any other power saving features.
2. "vmware tools"/"virtualbox guest additions"?
3. you can see apache restarting but no access? open shell with ping command and see if it only network problem.

Comment: 1.  No ACPI.

2.  No (it's a dedicated virtual instance).

3.  Not a network problem-- restart always fixes.

Comment: Seems to have been resolved with updates.  FWIW.